# UICollectionView in embedded view controller does NOT call cellForItemAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uicollectionview

I have 2 view controllers embedded in a view vertically.  View controller A (uploader), and B (docList). 
B contains a UICollectionView

All, methods except cellForItemAtIndexPath inside the datasource of the collection view get called correctly, and i double checked everything.  There is 1 section.  There are more than 0 rows.  The size of the rows I return is smaller than the collection view, etc

Here's a diagram to illustrate the setup:

[image]

My issue is:
Unless i turn on setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to YES, cellForItemAtIndexPath will never be called.   If i set that property to YES on the View Controller B's view, then it does get called.   But the layout is then screwed up, because I am not using springs and struts.  We only use constraints here.

Do you know what i can be doing wrong when embedding the view controller that contains the UICollectionView?

Here is the code that embeds the two view controllers' views, and sets them as child controllers:

```
 - (MFFormBaseCell *)cellForComponent
    {
self.cell = [[MFFormBaseCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
[self.cell addSubview: uploader.view];
[self.cell addSubview: docList.view];

UIView* uploaderView = uploader.view;
UIView* docListView = docList.view;

NSMutableArray* tempConstraints = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

[tempConstraints addObjectsFromArray:
     [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat: @"V:|-8-[uploaderView]-1-[docListView]-8-|"
                                             options: NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing metrics:nil
                                               views: NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(uploaderView, docListView)]];


[tempConstraints addObjectsFromArray:
 [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat: @"H:|-[uploaderView]-|"
                                         options: NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing metrics:nil
                                           views: NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(uploaderView)]];

[tempConstraints addObjectsFromArray:
 [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat: @"H:|-[docListView]|"
                                         options: NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing metrics:nil
                                           views: NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(docListView)]];

uploaderConstraints = [tempConstraints copy];
[self.cell addConstraints: uploaderConstraints];

[self.embedder addChildViewController:uploader];
[uploader didMoveToParentViewController:self.embedder];



[self.embedder addChildViewController:docList];
[docList didMoveToParentViewController:self.embedder];
docList.view.frame = self.cell.bounds;


return self.cell;

}
```

And here is the code from View Controller B, that sets up the UICollectionView and a vertical flow layout for it.

```
- (void)modelDidLoad
{

    _dataSource = [[MFCardDataSource alloc] initWithData: self.cardModel];;

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *aFlowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];


    [aFlowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];

    _collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame collectionViewLayout:aFlowLayout];
    [_collectionView setDelegate: self];
    [_collectionView setDataSource:_dataSource];
    [_collectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    for (NSString* type in [MFCardCollectionModel typeArray])
        [_collectionView registerClass:[MFImageCard class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier: type];

    [_collectionView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [self.view addSubview:_collectionView];

    [self registerConstraintsForView:_collectionView];

    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;

    [super modelDidLoad];

}
```

And the contents of registerConstraintsForView:

```
-(void) registerConstraintsForView:(UIView*)collectionView
{
    NSDictionary* metrics = @{ @"padding": @PADDING  };

    NSDictionary* views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_collectionView);
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                               constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-padding-[_collectionView]-padding-|"
                               options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing
                               metrics:metrics
                               views:views]];

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                               constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-padding-[_collectionView]-padding-|"
                               options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing
                               metrics:metrics
                               views:views]];
}
```

Comment: I actually found that the issue is:  the Housing View Controller's frame (docList) is Too small.   So UICollectionView has some internal logic that checks if the housing Frame is large enough to display what's contained inside.  It won't call cellForItemAtIndexPath, if there is not enough height/width to show the cell....    I found the problem by just setting background color on the view controller's View, and saw that it's only 50 px tall.    Setting the constraint for that view controller's view to specify a larger static height, fixes the issue.   Like this:   V:|-[docListView(==600)]

Comment: In other words, the contained UICollection view will NOT return it's appropriate intrinsicContentSize, and will not cause it's parent to stretch, because it won't even start drawing it's cells, if the container's view is too small to render them....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around the problem by Subclassing UICollectionView, and using the subclass instead.

On the subclass I overrode 2 methods:

```
- (void) setContentSize:(CGSize)contentSize
{
    CGSize origSize = self.contentSize;
    [super setContentSize:contentSize];
    if (!CGSizeEqualToSize(contentSize, origSize))
    {
        [self invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
    }
}

- (CGSize) intrinsicContentSize
{
    return CGSizeMake(UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric, self.contentSize.height);
}
```

Then, i have a method inside my view controller which contains the Collection View,  which calculates the required Height needed for the collection view.
I then call setContentSize with the calculated height on my subclass of Collection View, and that makes sure that it returns an intrinsicContentSize as tall as it needs to be to show all the card records inside it.